# answer a comment in google play

Tags: android, google-play

I receive a question in a comment in my app in Android, I would like to answer the user, I could't find how to do this, so, I looked in google and find this:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2012/06/replying-to-user-reviews-on-google-play.html

It was published on June, the 21, so it should be possible, but I can't.

The comment I want to answer to is the only one in my app, could this be the reason I can't answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to have recieved (Top Developer) status from the Google Play team.

Comment: and how can I get this? with downloads?

Comment: no, by being top developer. Like Rovio (Angry Birds series) for example.

Comment: You get this by making some sort of a killer app that the Google Play team likes. something that is very well put together, very well supported, and has hundreds of thousands of users.